# Simulink "Counter Limited" block with dynamic upper limit

Tags: simulink

The Simulink Library Block "Counter Limited" (Simulink/Sources/Counter Limited) counts up from zero to a specified upper limit. It then wraps round to zero and counts back up. This happens at a defined rate (sample time). The mask parameters are "Upper Limit" and "Sample Time".

My simulation contains a discrete-time cyclic process with a variable cycle duration, i.e. the number of samples per cycle varies (sample time is constant).

**Question:** Does anyone know how to make the mask parameter "Upper Limit" dynamic? I would like to pass the number of samples for the current cycle to the "Counter Limited" block at the beginning of each cycle. The current number of cycles is calculated in Simulink but I don't know how to pass it to the "Counter Limited" block correctly.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions offered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to *roll your own* counter implementation.  Something like the following will enable the reset value (in this case 6) to be specified as a signal rather than a parameter.  Note that the Unit Delay in the feedback path is needed to prevent an algebraic loop.

[image: Custom Limited Counter]

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up doing something very similar. I copied the contents of block Simulink/Sources/Counter Limited and replaced the component "Wrap To Zero" with my own function code. This allows me to feed the sample count of the current cycle back to the counter. Thanks again for your reply, much appreciated!

Comment: Just re-read my comment and saw it is not quite clear. By **sample count** I mean the total number of samples for the current cycle, i.e. the cycle duration divided by the sampling time (and then rounded to the nearest integer). By **counter** I mean the actual variable that is incremented by one per sample.